# what's the recommendation for adding javascript fragments to wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is more of a semantics advice request:

I have a little screen in my WP admin>settings and it just needs literally a couple of lines of javascript added. My first thought is to do it like this:

```
add_settings_section('social_options_facebook_connect', '', 'social_facebook_section_text', 'social');


function social_options_facebook_connect(){
    echo '
    <script>
    //throw a function in here which is about 2 lines long
    </script>';
    //button
    echo '<input name="Submit" type="submit" onclick="javascript:myFunctionCallHere()" value="Connect Site To Facebook" class="button-primary"  style="margin:20px;" />';
}
```

but this seems a little dirty. 
What is the recommended way of doing this?

thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually include a check to only load the extra stuff on the page it's required on. That way you're not adding it to every page in the admin. Assuming it's not necessary on every page!

It's probably not going to be of much benefit in this case but if you start adding more and more it definitely helps the speed of your admin pages.

```
$_current_page = isset($_GET["page"]) ?  $_GET["page"] : "";

if ($_current_page == 'social') {
    function social_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'social_script_1', 'url-for-script', '', '1.0.0', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'social_script_2', 'url-for-script', '', '1.0.0', true );
    }
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'social_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts . This example shows how to limit it to only your .php pages.

Comment: yeah, I was hoping this wasn't necessary for only a couple of lines of code.. but I guess it's cleaner